# GetOrgChart still zoom using gesture on mobile device

Tags: getorgchart

I'm using GetOrgChart js, it provided the function for **enableZoom** which will not zoom in website using mouse scroll, however, when deploy it with cordova, it still allow zooming for gesture (two fingers scale in/out), any ways to prevent it in mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following tag in your head element

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```